# sort a 'handsontable' and then be able to read the data back out of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I want to be able to sort a handsontable and then be able to read the data back out of the table. I have cobbled together this code which works, but it seems like there is better way to sort data on screen then be able to extract data in sorted order.

This javascript plugin seems to optimized for quick screen manipulation. "Only the table view is sorted. The data source remains in the original order." To sort both table view and datasource to sort it seems you have to do both or datasource and then re-apply.

references:
http://jsfiddle.net/itp99/paokya7y/6/

Documentation suggests that we use sort and render function, but then we still have to deal with sort order issue.

Documentation:
https://github.com/handsontable/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Understanding-column-sorting-plugin
http://handsontable.com/demo/sorting.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="../jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script src="../handsontable/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="../handsontable/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var sortCol = 0;
        var mySortDirection;

        var myArrayOfArrays = [         
            [66,'AA',1],
            [55,'BB',3],
            [44,'CC',2]
        ];

        // ----------------------------------------------------
        // HandsTable Setup
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        $('#exampleGrid').handsontable({
            data: myArrayOfArrays,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            colHeaders: true,
            contextMenu: true,          
            columnSorting: true,

            // use special listener to get column number, then sort underlying array as this is not default behaviour.          
            afterOnCellMouseDown: function (changes, source) {
                if (source['row'] === -1) { 
                    sortCol = source['col'];                    
                    // get current sort direction
                    mySortDirection =  sortDirection($('#exampleGrid').handsontable('getInstance'));
                    var myTableData = $('#exampleGrid').handsontable('getData');                    
                    // perform sort with custome callback
                    myArrayOfArrays = myArrayOfArrays.sort(fnSortingFunction);
                    // $('#exampleGrid').handsontable('render'); 
                    // display content of original array back to to screen
                    $('#textOut').html("");
                    fnShowArray(myArrayOfArrays);
                }
            }
        });  // end handsontable definition


        // ----------------------------------------------------
        // Sort function - callback
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        function fnSortingFunction(a,b) {           
            if (mySortDirection === 'Ascending'){
                if (a[sortCol] < b[sortCol]) return -1;
                if (a[sortCol] > b[sortCol]) return 1;
            }
            else{
                if (a[sortCol] < b[sortCol]) return 1;
                if (a[sortCol] > b[sortCol]) return -1;         
            }
            return 0;
        }   

        // ----------------------------------------------------
        // Determine which way to sort, TO DO: fix bugs?
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        function sortDirection(thisTable){      
            if (thisTable.sortingEnabled && typeof thisTable.sortColumn != 'undefined') {
                //if sortOrder === false, the order is descending, so make it ascending
                if(thisTable.sortOrder === false){ 
                    thisTable.sortOrder = true;
                    return "Ascending";
                }
                else{
                    thisTable.sortOrder = false;
                    return "Descending";
                }
            }
            else{               
                thisTable.sortOrder = true;
                return "Ascending";
            }
        };

        // ----------------------------------------------------
        // Show content of array back to Screen
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        function fnShowArray(myArrayofArrays){          
            $('#textOut').append("<br/><b>Dump Table Data: </b><br/>");
            $.each( myArrayofArrays, function( index1, myRow ) {                                            
                $.each( myRow, function( index2, myCell ) {                                         
                    $('#textOut').append(myCell + " - " );
                });
                $('#textOut').append("<br/>");
            });
        };

    }) // end jquery

</script>   

<div id="exampleGrid" class="dataTable"></div>
<div id="textOut" ></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you read the data out the array instead

Comment: This javascript plugin seems to optimized for quick screen manipulation. "Only the table view is sorted. The data source remains in the original order." To sort both table view and datasource to sort it seems you have to do both or datasource and then re-apply.

Comment: Sorting an array is much easier than extracting the data from an html table IMO

Comment: thanks for you input!  In my example, after sorting the hansontable html table, I sort the data source array with myArrayOfArrays.sort(fnSortingFunction).

Comment: One of the [getData](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta3/Core.html#getDataAtCell) variations might be helpful